# how a file can execute script to my server?

Tags: php, security, file-upload, upload

I have a simple file manager for my site, with these allowed extensions `['jpg','gif','png',zip,'rar','7z']`.

after a user uploads a file to the server, the script checks the file name, extension, size and mime type.
the file name must be alphanumeric and each `.` and `-` characters will convert to `_`.

if a user puts PHP script in his file, can that script execute by the server?
as I know web server doesn't treat `non-php` extension file as PHP script.

so is it safe enough?
what else i should do?

**update:**
sorry, I'm not professional in php,
please write more details and explain more why it's safe or not.

Comment: you should use the mime type `finfo()`. also i would advise that you have a separate sub-domain to handle file uploads `file-domain.mywebsite.com`. just to be safe.

Comment: @Akintunde007 I check mime type as I said in my question. how sub-domain can be effective?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, if a script is hidden in a image file or an archive it won't be executed, since it don't get interpreted as php code.

Comment: so, you say it's safe?

Comment: Yes. As already mentioned it don't get interpreted as php code. But just for example: if a user would name his file test.jpg.php and your script would upload  those file, it would be callable since it gets interpreted as php.